# Memoir manual: "The numbering of parts has no effect on the numbering of \chapters."

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, memoir

I am writing my PhD using `memoir` class. I have 5 parts, divided into chapters. But before the first chapter of each part, I have an introduction to what the following chapters are about. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Part}

\section{An introduction to First Part}

\chapter{First chapter of First Part}

\section{First section of First chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter of First Part}

\section{First section of Second Chapter}

\section{Second section of Second Chapter}

\part{Second Part}      

\section{An introduction to Second Part}

\chapter{First chapter of Second Part}

\section{First section of First chapter}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that, until the first chapter of a new part is created, the headers are still related to the previous chapter and previous section, which is not what I intended.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Could you use unnumbered section headers to start the introductions to each part?

Comment: Parts in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) (and the standard LaTeX document classes) are set on their own page. Similarly, issuing `\chapter` also puts it on its own page. Is that the intended behaviour you're after for you **Introduction** section... to be left alone on a page of its own?

Answer (score 2):

This is the behaviour of the standard classes.

If I understand your structure, the parts introductions are not part of any chapter, so maybe you shouldn't use \section title. If you want a title anyway, you may use non-numbered section: \section*

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Part}

\section*{An introduction to First Part}

\chapter{First chapter of First Part}

\section{First section of First chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter of First Part}

\section{First section of Second Chapter}

\section{Second section of Second Chapter}

\part{Second Part}      

\section*{An introduction to Second Part}

\chapter{First chapter of Second Part}

\section{First section of First chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Memoir uses a continuous pagestyle, with single-page interruptions (`\thispagestyle{x}`) at strategic element boundaries. This makes a good solution quite difficult for the structure you are using.

So I'd recommend making your introductions into first-class citizens by using `\chapter` rather than `\section`.

An alternative solution, a bit clunky in my opinion, is this:

In you preamble, define a new page style:

```
\copypagestyle{plainhead}{headings}
\makeevenhead{plainhead}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plainhead}{}{}{\thepage}
```

Then, for each part, add the necessary changes of page style:

```
\part{Another part...}
\pagestyle{plainhead}
\section{Introduction...}
... 
\clearforchapter
\pagestyle{headings}
\chapter{First chapter in new part...}
```

This *doesn't* solve any problems you may have with weird section numbering for the introduction sections, though. 
Turning the introductions into chapters in their own right is the best path, I believe.